# The output of the time series appears to be shifted

Tags: python, time-series, data-science, lstm

I have implemented a KERAS bidirectional LSTM for time series forecasting. My data is collected at a 10 s interval for 3 days. 
The output of the LSTM appears to be shifted by one time period.

My input is univariate. The output variable is forecast at t+1.

Data has been reshaped as (trainX.shape[0], 1, trainX.shape[1])

All help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.
Edit 1: Added Code

```
trainX = np.reshape(trainX,(trainX.shape[0], 1, trainX.shape[1]))
testX = np.reshape(testX,(testX.shape[0], 1, testX.shape[1]))
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(64,input_shape=(trainX.shape[1], trainX.shape[2]),stateful=False)))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
```

Edit 2 Added Data

```
Sample Data:
   Timestamp    X       Y       Predicted Y
1/01/2019 22:10 0   2       1.712
1/01/2019 22:20 2   0       3.813
1/01/2019 22:30 0   3       1.712
1/01/2019 22:40 3   0       4.829
1/01/2019 22:50 0   0       1.712
1/01/2019 23:00 0   21      1.712
1/01/2019 23:10 21  0       22.71
1/01/2019 23:20 0   0       1.712 
1/01/2019 23:30 0   0       1.712
1/01/2019 23:40 0   0       1.712
1/01/2019 23:50 0   0       1.712
```

Comment: Please show the code and data, then it's easier to help.

Comment: I added the code for the network and how i am reshaping the data. THe data is just values that have been recorede for 3 days with a 10 second interval. I am new to LSTM implementations. Thank you :)

Comment: Just show us some made-up example data, random-seeded or whatever. And the output that shows that it's shifted by one time period.

Comment: I added sample data as requested.

Comment: https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-lstm-models-for-time-series-forecasting/. I was trying to follow the tutorial here.